# Using UK switches in Slovakia

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, dimmer-switch

I have checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) to compare electricity in the UK vs Slovakia, see:

```
Country         PlugType    PlugStandard    Residential voltage Frequency   Comments
Slovakia        C, E        STN 34 4516                 230 V       50 Hz
United Kingdom  G[44]       BS 1363                 230 V[45]       50 Hz   Bathrooms may have shaver sockets
```

We can see the *Frequency* and the *Voltage* are the same. Obviously, I will not be using plugs as they are different.

**Question:** are the UK switches fully compatible with Slovakia?

**More detail:** the wiring is not in place yet, property is new built. I am planning to use dimmer switches for LED lights. The reason to use the UK products, they are surprisingly cheaper and have more varieties to choose from.

I have contacted the UK switch providers, and they keep saying there will be no warranty as they are not designed for EU. I am suspecting they are just playing safe not because products are not compatible.

I have also contacted Slovakia and the UK electricians, and cannot get a final answer, some say it is OK, some say it is not.

Any insight, suggestions?

Comment: what about the electrical inspector? ... also, if you use UK components, and you have a fire, then the insurance company will probably not pay.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks that is a concern, too. I guess this will be covered by the Slovak electricians "sign-off" papers.

Comment: I'm sure UK has some sort of trade agreement with Slovakia that says each must honor the other's technical certifications if they are reasonable... US has this with EU.  Otherwise trade agreements are worthless, as every foreign product could be  *coincidentally* rejected on technical grounds...  Rejecting a perfectly good UK switch is silly...

Answer (score 2):

Electrically they should be safe and function well. Both are EU member states - so standards are theoretically harmonised.

The problems may be that UK light switches are designed for use in UK back-boxes and patresses. The dimensions of the box and the location and dimensions/threads of the fixing screws (which are always included with UK switches) may be different to those used in Slovakia.

Labelling of connections in UK switches may be unfamiliar to Slovakian electricians (e.g. "Com", "L1" and "L2") but that should be a minor issue.

Comment: Had to look up the word [pattress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattress)! Good point, before buying we will of course check if all the pieces fit together. My question was would it (as you put it) "Electrically" work, which you answered already. Thank you. I will wait couple of days, to see if anyone disagrees.

Comment: Regarding language, however minor, we will have English speakers on site to advise.